# Removing .html extension from website

Tags: html

`<center><button onclick="window.location.href='/shop.html'">SHOP</button></center>`

I am trying to remove the .html tag from /shop.html. I have created a .htaccess file inside of my root folder. I included the follow inside;

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I then removed the .html from /shop.html and had no luck with error 404.

Cheers, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

1. If the requested URL does not have an extension:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
   ```
2. And it is not a directory:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   ```
3. And it is not a file:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   ```
4. And if by adding `.html` we find a file:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
   ```
5. Then add `.html` and serve that file:

   ```
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
   ```

Comment: do i remove the .html from the shop.html now? 
eg. 

     `<center><button onclick="window.location.href='/shop.html'">SHOP</button> 
    </center>`

will turn into 

     `<center><button onclick="window.location.href='/shop'">SHOP</button> 
    </center>`
????

Comment: The rewrite rules mean that you can request both `/shop` and `/shop.html` and the server will serve the same file. Note that the file on disk should still be named `shop.html`.

Comment: I removed the .html our of /shop but all i get is this; http://benjji.com/shop :/

Comment: Have you checked that you have `Options FollowSymLinks` and `RewriteEngine On` enabled on the directory? The are both needed.

Comment: sorry if i sound like a bit of a noob but this is my first time... How and where do I put these lines?

Comment: ^^^ if you can answer

Comment: @BenjaminBenjjiBerton: Apache [HTTP Server documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4).

Comment: what am i looking for?

Comment: You must have a `DocumentRoot` directive somewhere telling the server which directory corresponds to the URL `/`. Somewhere else you must have a `<Directory>` section specifying configuration options for that directory. `Options FollowSymLinks`, `RewriteEngine On` and the rewrite rules go into that section. If you want to place them in a `.htaccess` file then you must put `AllowOverride All` in the applicable `<Directory>` section -- but if you have access to the server configuration files, why do you want to use `.htaccess`?